# jquery remove selected attribute on option not working IE 7 & 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, selected

I have struggled to solve this one. What I have is parent/child select boxes next to each other that are generated dynamically based on what parent is selected.

What I would like to do is if I select one level up I remove the selected attribute on the selected children options.

The following code explains what im trying to do.

```
    <div id="selectBoxes">
      <select>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="parent">Parent</option>
      </select>
      <select class="mySelect">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="child">Child</option>
      </select>
      <select class="mySelect">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="grandChild">Grandchild</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('select').change(function() {
          var $nextSelects = $(this).nextAll('.mySelect');
          $nextSelects.each(function() {
                $(this).find('option:selected').prop("selected" , false);
           });
      });
    </script>
```

An example can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aLWTH/3/)

So what needs to happen is if all 3 options are selected and i move back lets say to the first select the 2 child selects are deselected. The above code works in FF and Chrome and IE 9 but not IE 7 & 8.

I have tried using .attr("selected" , "") & .removeAttr("selected") still wont work in IE.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$('select').change(function () {
    var $nextSelects = $(this).nextAll('.mySelect');
    $nextSelects.each(function () {
        $(this).val('');
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working in IE8 I dont have IE7 please check and revert

```
$('select').change(function () {
    var $nextSelects = $(this).nextAll('.mySelect');
    $nextSelects.each(function () {
      $(this).val("").prop("selected", true); 
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aLWTH/14/embedded/result/)

Second method

```
$('select').not(".mySelect").change(function () {      
    $(this).siblings('.mySelect').each(function () {
        $(this).find('option[value=""]').prop('selected', true);        
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aLWTH/10/embedded/result/)

The following also will work

`$(this).val("").prop("selected", true);`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aLWTH/12/embedded/result/)

Note jQuery1.10 not support in IE6,7,8 see [here](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/24/jquery-1-10-0-and-2-0-1-released/)